# Chart.js, set a max value

Tags: javascript, charts, chart.js

I am making a radar chart with `Chart.js`, but it only gets as big as the biggest value that's in it. I want it to be set to a standard max value, so the range is 0 to 100, and you can see how your progress is on different topics. Does anyone know how to set a max range of value to the radar chart with `Chart.js`?

(I tried just adding an extra dataset that's set to 100 and making it invisible, but than you see that data if you hover over the points in the radar, so that doesn't really look right)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the scaleOverride to do this, like so

```
...
var myChart = new Chart(ctx).Radar(data, {
    scaleOverride: true,
    scaleSteps: 5,
    scaleStepWidth: 20,
    scaleStartValue: 0,
});
```

---

Fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/bkm60q5y/

Comment: I'm trying to do the same in a PolarArea chart. But did not. Is these arguments supposed to work with PolarArea?

Comment: Yes, it does. Only bad arguments that I passed. Everything ok. Thanks @potatopeelings.