# Set min, max and number of steps in radar chart.js

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I am using chartjs.org 2.2.1 and have a radar chart that has values between 1..5. I want to set the min value to 0 and max to 5 with a step of 1.

This seemed to be answered exactly here in this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33011814/chart-js-set-a-max-value). However my charts still have a weird scale and not the one that I have defined as per my code below.

Can anyone see what I am doing wrong here?

```
    var options = {
        responsive: false,
        maintainAspectRatio: true
    };

    var dataLiteracy = {
        labels: [
            @PointLabel("Literacy", 1), @PointLabel("Literacy", 2), @PointLabel("Literacy", 3),
            @PointLabel("Literacy", 4), @PointLabel("Literacy", 5)
        ],
        datasets: [
            {
                label: "Literacy",
                backgroundColor: "rgba(179,181,198,0.2)",
                borderColor: "rgba(179,181,198,1)",
                pointBackgroundColor: "rgba(179,181,198,1)",
                pointBorderColor: "#fff",
                pointHoverBackgroundColor: "#fff",
                pointHoverBorderColor: "rgba(179,181,198,1)",
                data: [
                    @PointValue("Literacy", 1), @PointValue("Literacy", 2), @PointValue("Literacy", 3),
                    @PointValue("Literacy", 4), @PointValue("Literacy", 5)
                ]
            }
        ]
    };

    var ctx = $("#chartLiteracy");
    var myRadarChart = new Chart(ctx,
    {
        type: 'radar',
        data: dataLiteracy,
        options: options,
        scaleOverride: true,
        scaleSteps: 5,
        scaleStepWidth: 1,
        scaleStartValue: 0
    });
```

Answer (score 46, accepted):

You are right, but only if you are using Chart.js ***v1.x***.

Ticks options have changed in ***v2.x*** (the one you are using).

---

If you want to edit radar ticks, you will need to edit the `ticks` attribute in your chart options :

```
var options = {
    scale: {
        ticks: {
            // changes here
        }
    }
};
```

From what you need (mak a scale from 0 to 5), you can either :

- set the attribute `beginAtZero` to true and `max` to 5
- set the attribute `min` to 0 and `max` to 5

You can see [here](https://jsfiddle.net/w9e6rkau/) the result.

Answer (score 20):

Set the value of `stepSize`

```
scale: {
    ticks: {
        beginAtZero: true,
        max: 5,
        min: 0,
        stepSize: 1
    }
}
```

Comment: Perfect, work very nice here, thanks.

Comment: Very strange, your answer of 2019 definitely helped but in 2023, I had to make some changes. I won't say it's an *update* since it's written nowhere, but I had to use the new object path : *options.scales[scaleId].tricks* and i had to put the begin at zero outside the tricks inside the *options.scales[scaleId]* otherwise my min value was set as the min of the chart.

Answer (score 18):

Starting **ChartJS 3** the min/max scale values are not specified in `scale.ticks` but in `options.scale` or `options.scales[id]` object, example :

```
new Chart(hostElement, {
    type: "radar",
    data,
    options: {
        scale: {
            min: 0,
            max: 100,
        },
    },
});
```

https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/axes/radial/linear.html#linear-radial-axis :

> scales.[x/y]Axes.ticks.max was renamed to scales[id].max
> scales.[x/y]Axes.ticks.min was renamed to scales[id].min

https://codepen.io/JCH77/pen/abNymae

Answer (score 7):

Only this schema worked for me on **v3.8.0**

```
 options: {
   maintainAspectRatio: false,
   scales: {
     r: {
       min: 0,
       max: 5,
       beginAtZero: true,
       angleLines: {
         color: "red",
      },
    },
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

In chart.js V3 you can do this for the radar type:

```js
  options : {
       responsive: true,
       maintainAspectRatio: false,
       scales: {
          r: {
          min: 0, // MIN
          max: 5, // MAX
          beginAtZero: true,
          angleLines: {
             display: true,
             // color: 'red',
          },
          grid: {
           circular: true,
          },
          ticks: {
           stepSize: 1, // the number of step
          },
        },
      },
     }
```