# Chart.js: How to handle very large and very small values in radar chart?

Tags: charts, chart.js, chart.js2

Radar chart works fine if the values for different labels are relatively same in size. [ [**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/s72khfcg/1/) ]

[image]

If any label has a very large value relative to other labels, chart gets squeezed to a straight line. Which looks horrible.
 [ [**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/rkq82yqt/1/) ]

[image]

[**This question**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33011814/chart-js-set-a-max-value) shows how to set custom `scaleStepWidth` and `scaleStep`,
but if I use it Chart goes past its boundaries.
 [ [**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/xry4gz0e/1/) ]

[image]

is there any way to set different `scaleStepWidth` for different labels ?

Comment: I hope there isn't because that would be a data viz disaster.

Comment: Using a radar chart with your values is a bad idea IMHO. Radar charts values are usually on a small scale (*from 1 to 10 for instance*). You'd better use a bar chart instead. Do you **have to** use the radar chart in your project ?

Comment: @Tektiv  I did use `Bar` chart but instead of **1** quadrilateral `Radar` I had to distribute it in **4** `Bar Charts`. I wanted Radar because of it's overlapping polygons, the area of polygon then acts as the comparison factor, which in my case was the necessity of the situation. I tried to normalize the values in `[0 - 100] limit` but then I lost actual information.

Comment: @teylyn I've never worked with graphs before, I just thought that it would be nice to have 1 graph instead of 4 :)

Comment: Have you considered stacked bar charts?

Comment: Thanks all. I'm off of this now.

Answer (score 2):

Convert all your values to percentages of the series total. Then you have numbers that make sense to compare and you can plot them on the same scale.

Comment: thanks for your suggestion but i said earlier that `I tried to normalize the values in [0 - 100] limit but then I lost actual information.` which I guess is the same thing, anyway I dont't want to use workarounds , I guess Bar charts are the only solution